# Is there a way to convert HTML into normal text without actually write it to a selector with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I understand so far that in Jquery, with html() function, we can convert HTML into text, for example,

```
$("#myDiv").html(result);
```

converts "result" (which is the html code) into normal text and display it in myDiv.

Now, my question is, is there a way I can simply convert the html and put it into a variable?

for example:

```
var temp;
temp = html(result);
```

something like this, of course this does not work, but how can I put the converted into a variable without write it to the screen? Since I'm checking the converted in a loop, thought it's quite and waste of resource if keep writing it to the screen for every single loop.

**Edit:**

Sorry for the confusion, for example, if result is `" <p>abc</p> "` then `$(#mydiv).html(result)` makes mydiv display `"abc"`, which "converts" html into normal text by removing the `<p>` tags. So how can I put `"abc"` into a variable without doing something like `var temp=$(#mydiv).text()`?

Comment: What do you mean by `convert`? `.html()` basically sets the `.innerHTML` of the target element. There is no conversion.

Comment: What is in / what do you think is in `result`??

Comment: What do you mean by converting HTML into text? I'm very sure if `result` is a string of HTML markup, *the HTML markup* is placed into the `div` *as is*.

Comment: @PeeHaa: A string containing HTML, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: jquery has `.serialize()`, and the json library has `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: @Blender: exactly so thats what you want right?

Comment: @PeeHaa: The question is vague. I don't have a clue about what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: @Blender: thought you were OP :P

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, for example, if result is " <p>abc</p> " then $(#mydiv).html(result) should make mydiv display "abc". which "converts" html into normal text by removing the <p> tags. So how can I put "abc" into a variable without doing something like this: var temp=$(#mydiv).text();

Comment: @eastboundr: The `html` method doesn't do any such conversion. The `<p>` tags are not removed, they are parsed into a paragraph element. The element is put into the `mydiv` element, so it's actually the paragraph element that shows the text, not the `mydiv` element.

Comment: Thanks Guffa, so is there anyway to acquire the String "abc" string without displaying it anywhere on the page?

Comment: @eastboundr: To get the text from that specific string, you can use `var temp = $(result).text();`, i.e. turning the string into elements, then getting the text content from the one element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the `html` method doesn't turn HTML code into text, it turns HTML code into DOM elements. The browser will parse the HTML code and create elements from it.

You don't have to put the HTML code into the page to have it parsed into elements, you can do that in an independent element:

```
var d = $('<div>').html(result);
```

Now you have a jQuery object that contains a `div` element that has the elements from the parsed HTML code as children. Or:

```
var d = $(result);
```

Now you have a jQuery object that contains the elements from the parsed HTML code.

Comment: I know but it's not clear from the question if he wants the text in the variable as a string or if he wants a jQuery object.

Comment: @ToniToniChopper: What did you respond to there, actually?

Comment: Sorry, a case of selective blindness. I saw your answer as a comment to my answer and not as a standalone answer. Tired, long day

Comment: Thanks Guffa, yes this should work, since we are just setting a variable internally, instead of keep changing the content of a displayed div over 100 times externally. I think this is what I want, I will give it a try.

Comment: @Guffa, Thanks alot  " var d = $(result).text(); " kinda works, however, there is still slight difference between their lengths. By which I mean, When I do 

$("#mydiv").html(result);
var c = $("#mydiv").text().length;

var d = $(result).text().length;

c is "3 characters" longer than d. Very strange, any thoughts?

Comment: I think it has to do with the difference in .text() function alone and .text() after .html(). I will perhaps look into it later. for now it's good enough for the time being. Thanks again.

Comment: I see. You have some spaces around the paragrapgh tag, which will be parsed into textnode elements, and the `text` method concatenates the text from all elements. (But I don't know exactly why this doesn't happen when you put the code into the page.) You would use `$(result).filter('p').text()` to only get the text from the paragraph element.

Comment: @Finesse: When jQuery gets outdated, so does this question. Noone will go here looking for a non-jQuery solution.

Answer (score 16):

Here is no-jQuery solution:

```
function htmlToText(html) {
    var temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = html;
    return temp.textContent; // Or return temp.innerText if you need to return only visible text. It's slower.
}
```

Works great in IE ≥9.

Comment: This solution is not safe - you need to trust the html source in that case

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: @GalBracha `innerHTML` doesn't execute the `<script>` tags, so your solution is excessive

Comment: [MDN specify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations) that altough you can't run script in it you can still run malicious XSS code such as `const name = "<img src='x' onerror='alert(1)'>";
el.innerHTML = name; // shows the alert`
"

Comment: @GalBracha You are right

Answer (score 8):

You could simply strip all HTML tags:

```
var text = html.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g, "");
```

Comment: thanks, but i tried var text = result.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g, ""); it did not work... what is html here? is it the html string?

Comment: @eastboundr: Yes, in this case `html` should be a HTML string. http://jsfiddle.net/tjuAu/

Comment: To keep paragraphs ....
var html = <html with paragraphs>;  
var text = html.replace(/(<\/p>)/g, "\n");
console.log(text);
text = text.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g, "");
console.log(text);

Comment: This doesn't sort out &lt; & &nbsp; etc

Comment: This doesn't work: `"<p>a<sdf<br/>asdf</p>".replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g, "");` it returns
`"aasdf"`

Comment: This breaks for "are you < then 30" will return "are you" - see my answer below

Answer (score 6):

you can try:

```
var tmp = $("<div>").attr("style","display:none");
var html_text = tmp.html(result).text();
tmp.remove();
```

But the way with modifying string with regular expression is simpler, because it doesn't use DOM traversal.

You may replace html to text string with regexp like in answer of user `Crozin`.

*P.S.*
Also you may like the way when `<br>` is replacing with newline-symbols:

```
var text = html.replace(/<\s*br[^>]?>/,'\n')
            .replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g, "");
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't checked my code, so there was a mistake: it was `$("<div>")` instead of `$("div")`. I've edited my answer

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `.text()`

```
$("#myDiv").html($(result).text());
```

Comment: Thanks, but pls note, I'm doing a paragraph trimming and checking, so I'm constantly checking the result in a big loop over many times, so if we do this, myDiv content will be changed over many many times. So I thought is there a way to skip the step to "write" to myDiv, but simply store the result into a variable and checking it "internally" over the loops.

Answer (score 0):

var temp = $(your_selector).html();

the variable temp is a string containing the HTML

Comment: in the case you want the HTML as a string

Comment: Thanks, I think Guffa's method works, simply $(result). thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

`$("#myDiv").html(result);` is not formatting text into html code. You can use `.html()` to do a couple of things.

if you say `$("#myDiv").html();` where you are not passing in parameters to the `html()' function then you are "GETTING" the html that is currently in that div element. 
so you could say,

```
var whatsInThisDiv = $("#myDiv").html();
console.log(whatsInThisDiv); //will print whatever is nested inside of <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

if you pass in a parameter with your `.html()` call you will be setting the html to what is stored inside the variable or string you pass. For instance

```
var htmlToReplaceCurrent = '<div id="childOfmyDiv">Hi! Im a child.</div>';
$("#myDiv").html(htmlToReplaceCurrent);
```

That will leave your dom looking like this...

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <div id="childOfmyDiv">Hi! Im a child.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest, safe solution - use [Dom Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34064434/395804)**

For more advanced usage - I suggest you try [Dompurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify)

It's cross-browser (and supports Node js). only 19kb gziped

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rootux/6mbtveoj/11/) I've created that converts HTML to text

```
const dirty = "Hello <script>in script<\/script> <b>world</b><p> Many other <br/>tags are stripped</p>";
const config = { ALLOWED_TAGS: [''], KEEP_CONTENT: true, USE_PROFILES: { html: true }  };
// Clean HTML string and write into the div
const clean = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty, config);
document.getElementById('sanitized').innerText = clean;
```

Input: `Hello <script>in script<\/script> <b>world</b><p> Many other <br/>tags are stripped</p>`

Output: `Hello world Many other tags are stripped`

Answer (score 0):

Using the dom has several disadvantages. The one not mentioned in the other answers: Media will be loaded, causing network traffic.

I recommend using a regular expression to remove the tags after replacing certain tags like br, p, ol, ul, and headers into \n newlines.